# de-serialize ASCII to struct

Tags: c++, padding

I have come up with the following structure to declare various formats if messages that are to be received from the network:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>


template<int T>
struct uint
{
    static uint<T> create(uint64_t value)
    {
        uint<T> r = {value};
        return r;
    }

    uint(uint64_t value)
    {
        v = value;
    }
    uint()
    {}

    uint<T>& operator =(uint64_t value)
    {
        v = value;
        return *this;
    }

    operator uint64_t() const
    {
        return (uint64_t)v;
    }

    unsigned long long v:T;
}__attribute__((packed));
```

example:

```
typedef uint<5> second_t;
```

suppose one of the message formats (which are auto-generated via some process) is like this:

```
struct seconds
{
    char _type;
    second_t _second;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Now suppose I would like to populate an instance of the above messahe using a string:

```
int main()
{
 seconds ii;
 const char *i = "123456";
// memset, memcpy,sprintf... ??? what to use here?
 std::cout << ii._type << "  " << ii._second << std::endl;
}
```

Given a stream `123456`, I expect the instance of the `seconds` (`ii`) structure to have `char` `ii._type` = '1' and  integer `ii._second` = 23456. But I dont know how to do that.  Do you have a clue how i can do that? and do you have any suggestion how to improve the basic structure?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of easier and more reliable options available that require almost no work.

check out google protocol buffers (platform independent message serialisation and deserialisation): https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

or boost::serialization - (probably faster, but not platform-independant) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: Including another library might not be possible. can you point out the flaw that can render this implementation useless or inefficient?

Comment: @rahman _"Including another library might not be possible"_ Google protobuf also offers a c-language binding (nanopb) with an extremely small footprint. It was designed for use with embedded devices. It's not worth it to reinvent the wheel.